# How do I prevent dynamic code loading via eval in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, security, eval

Is there any way to prevent the use of eval and friends in nodejs code? It has been used by at least a couple of the npm malicious packages, and there is no reason for me to use it in my current project.

The fact that the unsafe-eval CSP declaration exists implies that it should be possible at the V8 level, but as far as I can tell, node doesn't expose this functionality. (if I had my way, banning eval would be the default...) I know the no-eval eslint rule exists, which is a good start, but I'm looking for something with runtime guarantees that includes node_modules as well.

Comment: What sort of program are you writing? Maybe show us some code.

Comment: It's just a basic express app, nothing fancy, although we are trying to be as security-conscious as possible because of our market segment, and most attacks start with arbitrary code execution. How would showing code help answer the question? It's pretty generic. I just want to make sure that something like `eval("console.log('hello world')")` doesn't work.

Comment: You can't change how Node.js interpret the code.

Comment: Would you say your question isn't necessarily about preventing loading via `eval()`, but primarily to detect the use of `eval()` in your projects and their dependencies?

Comment: @esqew Sure, so long as it includes dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to achieve what you're looking for using the --[disallow-code-generation-from-strings](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--disallow-code-generation-from-strings) command line option, or by setting the equivalent flag via NODE_OPTIONS ([supported in V12.16.0 and later](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v12.16.0)).

Answer (score -2):

You can't change how Node.js interpret the code unless you write/change the interpreter yourself. You can use linters like ESlint with the no-eval rule to make sure there is none in your code if it is not required.

`eval` is not in and of itself evil. It does serve some legit purposes.

It is only unsafe when you use it in an unsafe manner.

It's like a cooking knife. It is safe when you use it properly and use it for what it is made to do. If you try to pick your teeth with it, you can. But it is probably not a good idea.

What you are asking now is like asking how can you not let a knife be sharp because it can potentially cut you.

There are other more important things to worry about.

1. Is your server secure without misconfiguration?
2. Did you actually install the right packages not some malicious ones with similar names waiting for you to make a typo?
3. Did you check the package content before just running `npm i`?
4. Did you accidentally commit sensitive information to your version control?
5. Is your database secured? Is it accidentally configured to be internet-facing while it should not be?

Just to name a few. There are hundreds perhaps thousands of other points that you should worry about in terms of the overall security of your system.

Side Note:
For 0-day vulnerabilities, you can only pray.

Comment: Yes, eval does have a couple useful purposes. Not many, but they are there. We do not use it, though. Let me ask you this: if you have a sharp kitchen knife that you're not using, do you put it back in the drawer or wait for someone to knock it off the counter and land on your foot?

Comment: As for 1-5, I am aware of all those things, and I'm reasonably confident in all those things, but they cannot be restated enough. While it won't be saving me, maybe it'll save someone else who reads this post.

Comment: For the record, I was not the one who downvoted this answer.

Comment: Well, ownvoting is what made StackOverflow, StackOverflow. But let me restate this: you can't change how Node.js interpret the code unless you write/change the interpreter yourself. (Kitchen knife is probably not a good enough example. I think uranium ores will be a better analogy)

Comment: This is both incorrect (you can indeed control this, using --disallow-code-generation-from-strings), and not a good take on the risks of eval. Eval is a performance and security footgun. Yes, it's sometimes *useful*, but in general there tend to be better ways to achieve your ultimate goal.

It's generally a good security practice to disable use of eval and eval-like things.